# How to plot only on specific candles - not all

Tags: plot, conditional-statements, pine-script

For a new indicator on tradingview in pine script, I like to plot a curve using only candle values that qualify my contition. For example candle 1, candle 4 and canle 7. All other should not be used for plotting.
The if statement does not accept a plot function inside the if statement.

How do I plot only for selected candles?

Regards
Sven

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please refer to [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question on this site, and thus get good answers. Being more precise about your issue, showing what is your code so far, and the errors you are facing, as well as what you have tried so far to solve the matter.

Comment: What have you tried? What kind of curve do you want to plot? Maybe draw something so we can understand better.

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=3
study("My Script")
// it must work like that: 
// plot(n == 1 or n == 4 or n == 7 ? close : na)
//but there's a bug, so you can do it changing a color:

col = n == 1 or n == 4 or n == 7 ? blue : white
plot(close, color=col)
```